# Print/Merge Template Challenge

Tags: message-templates, printmerge

I have a word doc (ODT) that uses Tokens and works fine when I am in and choose the file from my device to Print/Merge - it creates a beautiful merged document.

When I go to message template and create a new template using the same .ODT file - When I go to use it on a contact - the resulting message is blank.

Is there something I am missing here?

Thanks.
Civi 5.29.1 on Joomla 3.9.23 but I am not sure that is the issue here

Comment: not really an answer but I'm not sure you can do this directly. Second point is that not all recipients can read/open .odt files and if so they could be visually modified (style, font, length...) so I would rather recommend using the PDF extension. It merges fine any token and then your .pdf can be sent trough CiviCRM. With CiviRules on top, you can create nice automatic processes.